# $G$ is a monoid such that cancellation laws hold in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $G$ be a monoid such that cancellation laws hold in $G$ .Show that it is a group.

I want to use the fact that if $G$ is  non-empty set such that associativity holds in $G$ and the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions then $G$ is a group.

But I cant proceed anymore.Any hints

Comment: The result is not true, for example $G={\Bbb N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with operation addition.

Answer (score 2):

The result is not true in general but is true if $G$ is **finite**.

**Hint**.  Let $G=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ be a finite monoid in which the cancellation laws hold.  For any fixed $x\in G$, the elements
$$xa_1,\ldots,xa_n$$
are all different (this is a consequence of cancellation, see if you can provide the details).  Therefore these expressions give all $n$ elements of $G$, and in particular one of them must be the identity element $e$, say $xy=e$.  Then we also have
$$yxy=ye=y=ey$$
and so $yx=e$.  Thus $y$ is the inverse of $x$.